# Bash - How to pass arguments to a script that is read via standard input

Tags: bash

I am trying execute a script from standard input and also pass arguments to it. Is there a way to do it?

Let's say that I have the following:

```
cat script.sh | bash
```

How would I pass the arguments to the script?

I do not want to do this:

```
bash script.sh arguments
```

Nor this:

```
./script.sh arguments
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After [@ccarton's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514284/bash-how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-script-that-is-read-via-standard-input#comment10572110_8514318):

```
cat script.sh | bash -s - arguments
```

It's more portable than [@Michael Hoffman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8514318/1165181).

Comment: Thanks! This is really useful for automated setups via `curl .. | bash -s ..`. Is the *dash* really needed? It seems that it works like this: `cat script.sh | bash -s arguments`

Comment: @Alek In this context (according to `man bash`), `-` is equivalent is equivalent to `--`, which is typically used to signal the end of options. So, if you've got an argument that `bash` could misinterpret as one of *its* options, you'll want `--` to disambiguate.

Answer (score 55):

On Linux,

```
cat script.sh | bash /dev/stdin arguments
```

seems to work.

Comment: Excellent! Would not have guessed it.

Comment: cat script.sh | bash -s - arguments

Comment: That's good, that would surely work everywhere, whereas `/dev/stdin` might not.

Comment: @ccarton Your comment is a better answer. For the sake of posterity, would you consider entering it again as an actual answer?

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer it would be great to edit it to use `bash -s -` @MichaelHoffman

Comment: @rfay I agree it's a better answer but it's someone else's answer and it feels wrong to edit mine to duplicate someone else's.