# Bash - How to pass arguments to a script that is read via redirected standard input

Tags: bash, ssh

I would like to expand a little more on "[Bash - How to pass arguments to a script that is read via standard input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514284/bash-how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-script-that-is-read-via-standard-input/8514351#8514351)" post.

I would like to create a script that takes standard input and runs it remotely while passing arguments to it.

Simplified contents of the script that I'm building:

```
ssh server_name bash <&0
```

How do I take the following method of accepting arguments and apply it to my script?

```
cat script.sh | bash /dev/stdin arguments
```

Maybe I am doing this incorrectly, please provide alternate solutions as well.

Comment: The command-line args are insufficient for this application?

Comment: How do I supply command line arguments to `ssh server_name bash <&0
`, so that they are not interpreted as bash options?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
cat script.sh | ssh some_server bash -s - <arguments>
```

Answer (score 2):

`ssh` shouldn't make a difference:

```
$ cat do_x 
#!/bin/sh

arg1=$1
arg2=$2
all_cmdline=$*
read arg2_from_stdin

echo "arg1: ${arg1}"
echo "arg2: ${arg2}"
echo "all_cmdline: ${all_cmdline}"
echo "arg2_from_stdin: ${arg2_from_stdin}"

$ echo 'a b c' > some_file
$ ./do_x 1 2 3 4 5 < some_file 
arg1: 1
arg2: 2
all_cmdline: 1 2 3 4 5
arg2_from_stdin: a b c
$ ssh some-server do_x 1 2 3 4 5 < some_file
arg1: 1
arg2: 2
all_cmdline: 1 2 3 4 5
arg2_from_stdin: a b c
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I meant. Taking from your example `ssh some-server do_x 1 2 3 4 5 < some_file`, replace do_x by standard input: `bash <&0
`, and this line would be inside do_x script. So now, how would I pass the arguments?

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you trying to write your own shell in `do_x`?

Comment: I am trying to create a wrapper script that runs remotely any script provided. Also I would like to support any piped input.

Comment: instead of wrapping, why not just `source` in the features which should be common among scripts?

Comment: may not be an answer that OP wants, but good stuff!, thanks for sharing @BrianCain . Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but the wrapper script handles complex logic and I want to run **any** script through the wrapper without modifying those scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This variant on [ccarton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100158/ccarton)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8535579) also seems to work well:

```
ssh some_server bash -s - < script.sh <arguments>
```