# Redirect stdin script with parameters

Tags: bash, makefile, stdin, docker-machine

I'm trying to do redirect the stdin to the ssh on a server, but the script contains parameters.

I'm doing this inside a Makefile

```
./docker-machine ssh machine < scripts/provision-docker-images.sh "param1" "param2"
```

I tried many options like

```
 < $(scripts/provision-docker-images.sh "param1" "param2")
 <(scripts/provision-docker-images.sh "param1" "param2")
```

any idea?

Comment: Seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528716/bash-how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-script-that-is-read-via-redirected-standard-in)?

Comment: Does it work? `./docker-machine ssh machine< <(scripts/provision-docker-images.sh "param1" "param2")`

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism for connecting the standard output of one command to the standard input of another command is the *pipe*.  The shell's operator for that is `|`.  If I understand correctly that

- the script is supposed to run on the local host
- `docker-machine ssh` will forward its own standard input over the ssh connection to the remote shell

then what you want would be

```
scripts/provision-docker-images.sh "param1" "param2" \
    | ./docker-machine ssh machine
```

(line splitting optional).

In contrast,

- the redirection operator `<` is for redirecting a command's standard input to come from a *file*;
- the command substitution operator `$(...)` is for expanding the output of a command to form *part of* another command (similar to parameter expansion);
- the process substitution operator `<(...)` is for creating  *a file name* from which the output of a command can be read (i.e. designating the read end of a FIFO).

Comment: Hi. The script must to be run in the VM.
A friend gave me this solution and it works.

`./docker-machine ssh machine param1="param1" param2="param2" 'sh -s' < scripts/provision-docker-images.sh`